# filemaker implode array

Tags: filemaker

So lets say my calculation is this

```
Let (
    [
        $result[1] ="1";
        $result[2] ="!";
        $result[3] = "3";
        $result[4] = "4";
        $result[5] = "5";
        $result[6] = "6";
        $result[7] = "7";
        $result[8] = "8";
        $result[9] = "-";
        $result[10] = "10";
        $result[11] = "11";
        $result[12] = "12";
        $result[13] = "13";
        $result[14] = "14";
        $result[15] = "15";
        $result[16] = "!";
    ];  
    $result[1] & 
    $result[2] & 
    $result[3] & 
    $result[4] & 
    $result[5] & 
    $result[6] & 
    $result[7] & 
    $result[8] & 
    $result[9] & 
    $result[10] & 
    $result[11] & 
    $result[12] & 
    $result[13] & 
    $result[14] & 
    $result[15] &
    $result[16]
)
```

this is pretty straight forward I make and array and then I want to it to return the array as a string is there and easier way to concatenate the the values of the result array ?

** Sample custom functions ***
trying to use @chuck 's  code not sure what I'm doing wrong I could figure out how to upload a file so here are some mimages

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here's an alternate custom function for concatenating an array: http://www.briandunning.com/cf/1285

Comment: It looks like you entered the _ConcatArray custom function incorrectly, you should take off everything up to and including the first equals sign. Chuck's custom function looks like it will work fine, the one I linked to (which I wrote) has a few extra features, and is a single function.

Comment: @Sam Barnum .. that did it. I should have known that ... your link also looks good but still requres you to know the length of the array  thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's two custom functions that should work if you can assume that once you get to a blank value in the array, you've reached the end of the array. I wrote it very quickly and only tested it once, but perhaps it'll do the job for you.

`ConcatArray( VarName ) = _ConcatArray( VarName; 1 )`

This just calls a recursive function with an initial value.

```
_ConcatArray( VarName; Iteration ) = Let(
  [
    Var = Evaluate( "$" & VarName & "[" & Iteration & "]" )
  ];

  Case(
    IsEmpty( Var );
    "";
    Var & _ConcatArray( VarName; Iteration + 1 )
  )
)
```

I then opened the Data Viewer in FileMaker and tested it with this calculation.

```
Let (
    [
        $result[1] ="1";
        $result[2] ="!";
        $result[3] = "3";
        $result[4] = "4";
        $result[5] = "5";
        $result[6] = "6";
        $result[7] = "7";
        $result[8] = "8";
        $result[9] = "-";
        $result[10] = "10";
        $result[11] = "11";
        $result[12] = "12";
        $result[13] = "13";
        $result[14] = "14";
        $result[15] = "15";
        $result[16] = "!"
    ];  
    ConcatArray( "result" )
)
```

The result was `1!345678-101112131415!`.

Comment: can't seem to make this work not sure why it just gives me a ? in the field. as a side note if I can get this to work it will do the job for this project but it would be nice to know the length of a an array

Comment: Note first that this is a pair of custom functions. You have to have FileMaker Pro Advanced and use them as such. If you're using just FileMaker Pro, this won't work. You need FileMaker Pro Advanced to create custom functions, but once they're defined in a file, you can use them in FileMaker Pro.

Comment: Another thought: if you are working with hundreds of repetitions in the array, it may be running out of memory with the recursive function. If this is the case, you may want to think about storing the data in a different manner, such as in a temporary table. Try uploading a sample file that I can take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a recursive custom function. Specify the end range and the var name as parameters and it could then repeatedly call itself with an incrementing index number until that index number equaled the end range.

Comment: but what if you don't know the end range ? is there way to get the length of the array ?

Comment: No, there is no way. $result[10000000] could contain a value, and there is no practical way to find that out.

Comment: If you're able to assume that the array doesn't have any blank values, then a recursive custom function would work.